# Possible to append subviews once to grid in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js

I'm loading JSON data (array of objects) via service, onReady, and want to display this data in a grid. I have each row represented by a view.

```
        render: function(){
            var self = this;
            (self.collection.models).forEach( function(model){
                var rowView = new RowView({model: model});
                self.$el.append(rowView.render().el);
            });                
        }
```

Is it possible to build subviews and push them all at once to the DOM instead of going 1 by 1? Does the browser reflow & repaint happen on every append?

Ive seen all the ways people add subviews/children, but none of them solve the problem (frequent DOM access?) because this is just how backbone is built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that can be done. Generate an html element with jQuery (using the view's `tagName` definition and `attributes` and all that) and then append everything to that. When you're done, swap out the current `this.$el` with the new one:

```
render: function(){

  // create in memory element
  var $el = $(this.tagName);
  // also get the `className`, `id`, `attributes` if you need them

  // append everything to the in-memory element
  this.collection.each(function(model){
    var rowView = new RowView({model: model});
    $el.append(rowView.render().el);
  });

  // replace the old view element with the new one, in the DOM
  this.$el.replaceWith($el);

  // reset the view instance to work with the new $el
  this.setElement($el);
}
```

That should do it.

Of course, you're going to see a bit of a flicker on the screen, depending on how fast the browser is and how large the change is. But this should get you down the road to do what you want.

More info about replaceWith: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: If I don't define id/tagName/className, the element is created in memory correct? Does Backbone itself ever access the DOM when building views (automatically) ?

Comment: backbone never does anything with the DOM unless you tell it to. You can generate html elements all day long and never once touch the DOM. `$("<div>")` for example, will create an in-memory `<div>` element.

Comment: @Mike, if you don't pass an `el` argument to the view constructor, Backbone will automagically create a DOM element for you (using `tagName`, `className`, `id`, and `attributes`) and assign it to the `el` property of the view object, but it won't automatically insert it into the document.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a simpler solution than @Derick's answer:

```
render : function () {

  var children = [];

  this.collection.forEach( function( model ) {

    var rowView = new RowView( { model : model } );

    children.push( rowView.render().el );

  } );


  this.$el.empty().append( children );


  return this;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tXnTk/

Comments on code in @Derick's answer (my comments marked with "[JMM]:"):

```
render: function(){

  // [JMM]: You should already have this.el / this.$el, so there 
  // [JMM]: should be no need to mess with this.tagName, className, 
  // [JMM]: id, etc. Just store the child views in an array.

  // create in memory element
  var $el = $(this.tagName);
  // also get the `className`, `id`, `attributes` if you need them

  // append everything to the in-memory element
  this.collection.each(function(model){
    var rowView = new RowView({model: model});
    $el.append(rowView.render().el);
  });


  // [JMM]: Using replaceWith will wipe out event listener
  // [JMM]: registrations and other data associated with the
  // [JMM]: DOM element. That's why it's necessary to call
  // [JMM]: setElement() afterward. Since you already have
  // [JMM]: the DOM element and you just want to change the
  // [JMM]: content you might as well just empty it out and
  // [JMM]: append the new children.

  // replace the old view element with the new one, in the DOM
  this.$el.replaceWith($el);

  // reset the view instance to work with the new $el
  this.setElement($el);
}
```