# Backbone View.remove()

Tags: backbone.js

I just upgraded my Backbone to 0.9.2 and when I do a view.remove() like I did with the older version it no longer is working for me.

I have a popup.js view called processingView that just has some jquery code wrapped in an view extend. I assign this to a variable called processing.
this.processing = new processingView();
When I fire an event to remove the processing object from the Dom by saying. this.processing.remove() it no longer gets removed. If I revert back to the older version of Backbone it works.

Anyone got any ideas why this would be.
My code is a huge amount of source files so its hard to paste all this in here. But as far as what I'm trying to do it should be straight forward remove a view object from the dom.

**ANSWERED MY OWN QUESTION**

Ok I was not using setElement when I was manually setting View.el

If you've ever manually set this.el in a Backbone View to be a particular DOM element, you'll want to use setElement instead.

Its still not clear what the difference between view.el and view.$el. Maybe someone can straighten that out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view.$el` is equivalent to `$( view.el )`.  It's a convenience so that you don't have to incur the hassle and additional overhead of repeatedly calling the jQuery constructor.  You may want to structure your code (if possible) so that you don't need to manually set `el` and call `setElement`.  You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10339811/1034448) to another question for an example.

Comment: In older additions I never had to wrap el in a jquery object. I would pass it in through the constructor. var view= new View({el:$('.domEl')}). Then el was already a dom element reference. When I do that now I have to use $.el

Comment: Do you mean `el` was already a jQuery object?  I can't speak to behavior of prior verions, but Backbone 0.9.2 normalizes `view.el` to a DOM object and `view.$el` to a jQuery (or alternative library) object wrapping that DOM object. So passing a jQuery object as the `el` property to the constructor, as in your example, will store it as `view.$el` and will store the DOM object as `view.el`. If it didn't do that before, my guess is that it was changed to introduce consistency, so that `view.el` will always be a DOM object (at least, when setting `el` via the API (e.g. `setElement`)